# Reducing the amount of javascript files

Tags: javascript, package, concatenation, minify

quote from 'woorank.com':

> Too bad, your website has too many JavaScript files (more than 7).

i've already compressed all of my own javascript files into one. But the rest is just jquery plugins(cookie, form, easings, etc.).
Is there a way, e.g. via some sort of package selector, to return a jquery file with all selected plugins included? It would save some tedious editing and merging on my part!

thanks

Comment: Create a single json object including text of all files as properties of object ? Create a blob including all files appended to blob ?

Comment: it's often faster and more flexible to have two or three files; one is not enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at Grunt http://gruntjs.com/. It provides many plugin which can make your life a lot easier with these kind of taks.

Plugin for concatenation here : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat

Comment: Gulp can also do - or even component -